# Overset arrows similar to \vec for monomorphism, epimorphism and isomorphism

Tags: overset

I want to define 3 commands similar to `\vec`. The first, `\Mono`, must place over the argument an arrow just like in `\vec`, but with another arrowhead in the beginning of the arrow, and also pointing rightwards. This is to represent injections or monomorphisms.

The second,`\Epi`, must place over the argument an arrow just like in `\vec`, but with two arrowheads in the end of the arrow, both pointing rightwards. This is to represent surjections or epimorphisms.

The third, `\Iso`, must place over the argument an arrow just like in `\vec`, but with another arrowhead in the beginning of the arrow, but pointing leftwards. This is to represent bijections or isomorphisms.

My first attempt was to define the following commands

```
\newcommand{\Mono}[1]{\overset{\rightarrowtail}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Epi}[1]{\overset{\twoheadrightarrow}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Iso}[1]{\overset{\leftrightarrow}{#1}}
```

But these commands create too much space between the letter in the argument and the arrows above them, and the arrows themselves are too big. Ideally, I would like to know how `\vec` is defined and also to have commands that behave well in superscripts etc.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly how you defined `\rightrightarrow`, but my main point is to show  the layout will be better if you do that with the  `accents` package, as it takes into account the italic angle of the maths variables, so I replaced it with `\hookrightarrow`, which is a standard way to denote an injective homomorphism.

Here is a comparison of both ways:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{accents} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\Mono}[1]{\overset{\hookrightarrow}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Epi}[1]{\overset{\twoheadrightarrow}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Iso}[1]{\overset{\leftrightarrow}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{matrix}\Mono{f}: A \rightarrow B &\quad & \accentset{\hookrightarrow}{f}: A \rightarrow B \\%
 \Epi{f}: A \rightarrow B & & \accentset{\twoheadrightarrow}{f}: A \rightarrow B \\
 \Iso{f}: A \rightarrow B & & \accentset{\leftrightarrow}{f}: A \rightarrow B
\end{matrix}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will test this, but I still rather define a command instead of using this whole package just for this.

Comment: I changed \rightrightarrow to \rightarrowtail, I just didn't remember I used this command at the time I asked the question...

Comment: Of course, you may define new commands with `accents`. I did not want to do it in your place.

Comment: I didn't remember  \rightarrowtail. It's quite fine.

Comment: Oh, that's not what I meant. I mean, instead of defining a command using \accentset from thr package accents, I would prefer to define some kind of command (like \accentset, possibly) explicitly, directly.

Comment: Would it be too complicated?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Accents is a well established package, which works  fine. Too complicated… – for me, it wouldn't be easy to  declare a math  accent correctly.

Comment: I use \hookrightarrow for embeddings and (sometimes) extremal monomorphisms, that's why I choose the not-so-conventional \rightarrowtail

Comment: I see. Conventions also depend on the domain in which you work.

Comment: This command seems to work fine, and does not create extra space between lines when a write \accentset{\leftrightarrow}{C} on a the middle of the paragraph, which is great. When I use it with \mathscr, for instance \accentset{\leftrightarrow}{\mathscr{C}}, the arrow is placed too much to the right to my taste. Is there a way to correct this? Using \accentset{\leftrightarrow\ }{\mathscr{C}} gives a better result, but I wonder if there is a way to correct this for every time I use \accentset with \mathscr.

Comment: You can  correct it by hand adding `\mkern - n mu` (number of mathematical units) after the arrow in the argument of `\accentset`.